# foreach with $posts and $terms

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I am using [ACF relationship](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) field on a Wordpress site so that the admin user can easily determine which posts are visible on that page. I have a custom taxonomy where I need to be able to `get_the_terms` and print the term for each post. This is normaly achieved with an foreach as mentioned in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).

However Im using the foreach to get the `$posts` so I'm not sure how to use this to also print the term name in my `H3` and the term slug in the main `<div>`

Code below:

```
<?php
$posts = get_field('team_members',12);
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'position' );
if( $posts ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) 
    setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="col-4 col <?php echo $term->slug;?>">
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('team-item'); ?>>
            <hgroup>
                <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="alt-heading-4">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</h2>' ); ?>
                <h3><?php echo $term->name;?></h3>
            </hgroup>

            <div class="team-entry-content">
                <?php the_content();?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <div id="team-shadow"></div>
        </article><!-- #post-## -->
    </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So I don't need to read extensive documentation, is the `$post->ID` used in the `get_the_terms()` call relevant to the `$post` defined in iteration of `foreach ($posts as $post)`, or is that `$post` variable from earlier code?  In other words, are you retrieving terms for each post `ID` looped from `get_field()`?

Comment: $post->ID isn't used in get_the_terms. Everything would stay as is, except the foreach would look like 'foreach( $terms as $term)'

Comment: Due to unfamiliarity with WP, I am not fully certain of the intent, but it appears to me that what you need to do inside the outer `foreach ($posts as $post)`is another `foreach ($terms as $term)` nested within it, wherein you move the call to `get_the_terms()` to happen _inside_ the $posts `foreach` loop rather than before it.  But as I said, I'm unfamiliar with WP....

Comment: The algorithm I mean is: `$posts = get_field()...foreach($posts as $post) { $terms = get_the_term()... foreach ($terms as $term) {  //print term info } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the terms are connected to your post , you have to place the :

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'position' );
```

inside the foreach loop , outside that it will not work at all , as the `$post->ID` will be error:

```
trying to get the property of non object
```

so the solution is take the `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'position' );`  and add it inside the foreach loop:

```
<?php
$posts = get_field('team_members',12);
if( $posts ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) 
    setup_postdata($post);
       $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'position' ); ?>
    <div class="col-4 col <?php echo $term->slug;?>">
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('team-item'); ?>>
            <hgroup>
                <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="alt-heading-4">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</h2>' ); ?>
              <?php foreach($terms as $term) {?>
                <h3><?php echo $term->name;?></h3>
              <?php } ?>
            </hgroup>

            <div class="team-entry-content">
                <?php the_content();?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <div id="team-shadow"></div>
        </article><!-- #post-## -->
    </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i hope it did help :).

Comment: @probablybest  glad it helped you :).

Comment: I've found a weird bug where the first post doesn't get the $term->slug or $term->name. Any idea what could be causing that?  From the second post it then gets the terms. I tried creating different posts with different terms as the first post but it made no difference.

Comment: @probablybest  seems like first post does not contain terms maybe.

Comment: Deffinitely has the terms. I have tried changing the first post to one which I know works and changing the terms but it makes no difference.

Comment: @probablybest i did edit my answer try to use new updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94700/discussion-between-probablybest-and-arsh).